# How to change image upload size in Opencart 3

Tags: opencart, opencart-3

I'm looking for a way to increase image upload size in Opencart 3 from 300kb to 3mb

I tried to change
`oc_store/controller/setting/setting.php` [the 571 line in GH-repo](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/496d5b809b686e19c0a860356c4f740ed55894a8/upload/admin/controller/setting/setting.php#L571) from 300 000 to 3 000 000 to achieve approximate 3mb size.

`$data['config_file_max_size'] = 300000;`

Also I found a solution applicable to Opencart 2 only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In OpenCart 3 there is built in tool to change upload image size and there is no need to change the code:

Go to `Admin -> System -> Settings -> Server -> Max File Size`

One more tip:
To change preview image size from 300x300 - go to:

`admin -> Extension -> Extension -> Choose the extension type: Theme -> Product Image Thumb Size`